# Create Table with GetJSON Response in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, json

I'm trying to fetch some data from our database using jQuery's getJSON method. I am able to get a response without issues, but when I try to append it to the page, it's undefined.

Sample json:

`{
"ItemCount":1,
"ProductID":"4220002",
"ProdMfg":"",
"Desc":"",
"Quantity":33,
"UnitPrice":1,
"ExtPrice":33
}`

jQuery Code:

```
$.getJSON('webcatpageserver.exe?aShoppingCart', function(data) {
    var table = '<table>';
    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
        table += '<tr><td>' + item.ProductID + '</td><td>' + item.Quantity + '</td>    </tr>';
    });
    table += '</table>';
    $("#mini-pallet").append(table);
});
```

HTML:
In the HTML, I see "undefined" displayed.

I assume I'm not accessing the data properly in order to display it - but I could use a push in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: After dealing with issues stated in the answers below, you should also checkout: jQuery code references the ProdID property of item (`item.ProdID`) but there is no such property in the sample json you've provided.

Comment: This is corrected above. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely need a `push()` in the right direction, maybe an `array_push()` in your server page that creates the `getJSON` response. ;-)

Your response object is currently not an Array, so your `$.each()` will instead go through each of your properties in your json object and will then not find the expected properties again.

A json object like

```
[{ "ItemCount":1, "ProductID":"4220002", "ProdMfg":"", "Desc":"", "Quantity":33, "UnitPrice":1, "ExtPrice":33 }]
```

where you place your original objects as elements into an array would probably work.

Answer (score 0):

Your `each` loop, as said in another answers here, is not an array, nor a list. So you are iterating over each and every `item` but, you are not getting any string tags, as they are not objects and therefore, ignored.

The `push()` method can be handy here, but, just for explanation, you need to convert this each loop into actual string, so it will be recognized as an entire string, not an object.